# Angular no recognizing Leaflet TimeDimension

Tags: angular, leaflet, geojson, ngx-leaflet

I have installed leaflet-timedimension on an Angular project. I am using ngx-leaflet. I am not able to work with the geoJson time dimension, it seems that angular does not recognize the leaflet-timedimension plugin.

I receive this error: ERROR TypeError: can't access property "geoJson", leaflet__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.TimeDimension.layer is undefined

How can I import this plugin in the correct way? Is there some alternative for Angular in order to show lines on map following a timeline?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not imported correctly the plugin.

You should import the plugin like this:

```
import "leaflet-timedimension/dist/leaflet.timedimension.control.min.css";
import "leaflet-timedimension";
```

In the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-12-with-ngx-leaflet-leaflet-timedimension-r7k93v?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:108-214) below you can find this [example](https://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example17.html) adapted in Angular 12.x using ngx-leaflet